# Writing a spec for sending a mail via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, ruby-on-rails-4, bdd

I want an E-Mail to be sent using a background process whenever an `Invite` was generated.

What I currently have is this approach: The `Invite` model has the method `send_mail`, which sends an E-Mail using the Mandrill API and gem. It also has the method `queue_mail` adds `InviteMailer` with the invite's ID to the queue using Resque.

However… Since I'm having sort of a really hard time writing specs for this, I assume this might not be the best approach to send mails.

What I mainly want and need to test:

- was the mail added to the queue?
- is `InviteMailer` working properly?
- does the mail contain the correct vital information?

Vital informations are: sent to the correct person, contains a link to a specific site and some specific data/text; also I'm not sure how to get the current host to the link.

I don't think this is a rare thing to do, so I wonder what the best practices are.

My testing environment: rspec, capybara, factory girl. I already added VCR, to cache the API-request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/) to fake your mail server, and check received mail via web API:

> **Features**
>
> - Catches all mail and stores it for display.
> - Shows HTML, Plain Text and Source version of messages, as applicable.
> - Rewrites HTML enabling display of embedded, inline images/etc and open links in a new window. (currently very basic)
> - Can send HTML for analysis by Fractal.
> - Lists attachments and allows separate downloading of parts.
> - Download original email to view in your native mail client(s).
> - Command line options to override the default SMTP/HTTP IP and port settings.
> - Mail appears instantly if your browser supports WebSockets, otherwise updates every thirty seconds.
> - Growl notifications when you receive a new message.
> - Runs as a daemon run in the background.
> - Sendmail-analogue command, catchmail, makes using mailcatcher from PHP a lot easier.
> - Written super-simply in EventMachine, easy to dig in and change.
>
> **How**
>
> 1. `gem install mailcatcher`
> 2. `mailcatcher`
> 3. Go to `http://localhost:1080/`
> 4. Send mail through `smtp://localhost:1025`
>
> **API**
>
> A fairly RESTful URL schema means you can download a list of messages
>   in JSON from `/messages`, each message's metadata with
>   `/messages/:id.json`, and then the pertinent parts with
>   `/messages/:id.html` and `/messages/:id.plain` for the default HTML
>   and plain text version, `/messages/:id/:cid` for individual
>   attachments by CID, or the whole message with `/messages/:id.source`.